# How to pass a parameter to a new activity with tab host

Tags: android

I am passing a parameter to a new activity using tab host in android but it is showing an illegal exception

```
 Intent homeintent;   
 // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused) 
 homeintent = new Intent();
 Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
 String strusername=bundle.get("strUserName").toString();
 String strPassWord=bundle.getString("strPassword").toString();
 String questGroupId=bundle.getString("questGroupId").toString();
 homeintent.putExtra("strUserName", strusername);
 homeintent.putExtra("strPassword",strPassWord );
 homeintent.putExtra("questGroupId",questGroupId);
 homeintent.setClass(this, HomeActivity.class); 
 spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("home").setIndicator("Home",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.home_tab_bar_icon)).setContent(homeintent);
 tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Can anybody tell me how to pass a parameter using intent with tabhost in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the right way...  Give this a try too.. setClass of Intent before putting Data into it.