# ListView not being changed

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-listview, tabs

To start off I'm a beginner with this android programming.

My app has 2 activites defined in TabHost, hence Tab 1 and Tab 2. 
In Tab 1 I receive an EditText input that I would like to show in tab 2 (activity 2) in a ListView.

For this I created a Custom ListView with this tutorial: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter

Now:
I pass the EditText value as a String with the help of an intent in tab 1, to tab 2.

```
//Intent to tab 2
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Tab2Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("values", streetName);
startActivity(intent);
```

In my Tab 2 (Tab2Activity) I receive this intent like this:

```
public void onResume (){
    super.onResume();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        updateData(bundle);
    }
}

public void updateData (Bundle bundle) {
    String data = bundle.getString("values");
    Toast.makeText(this, data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Bostad bostad_data[] = new Bostad[]{new Bostad (streetName, money)};
    adapter = new BostadAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, bostad_data);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    ...
}
```

I have two question (two problems).

1) I know that since I call "startActivity(intent) in Tab1 this will open up the activity and not in the tab. Is it possible to just switch tab and update the listView? (This isn't necessary. Only if it's an easy solution)

2) I get the activity with the right info up on my screen, but the listView in Tab2 isn't updated with this information. How can I fix this? 
What I mean is, a row doesn't get added to the listview. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Adding the onCreate in Activity2 as well.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab2);

    //Create listView and connect to the .xml (activity_tab2)
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    //Arrayen which the list will receive values from
    Bostad bostad_data[] = new Bostad[]{
            new Bostad("", "")
    };
    adapter = new BostadAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, bostad_data);
    View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
    listView.addHeaderView(header);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    ...
}
```

Edit 2: Adding BostadAdapter.java

```
public class BostadAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Bostad> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    Bostad data[] = null;

    public BostadAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Bostad[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    BostadHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new BostadHolder();
        holder.gatunamn = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.gatunamn);
        holder.totalkostnad = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.totalkostnad);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (BostadHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Bostad bostad = data[position];
    holder.gatunamn.setText(bostad.gatunamn);
    holder.totalkostnad.setText(bostad.totalkostnad+" SEK per månad");

    return row;
    }

static class BostadHolder
{
    TextView gatunamn, totalkostnad;
}
}
```

Edit 3: Adding Bostad.java

```
public class Bostad {

String gatunamn, totalkostnad;

public Bostad (){
    super();
}

public Bostad (String gatunamn, String totalkostnad) {
    super();
    this.gatunamn = gatunamn;
    this.totalkostnad = totalkostnad;
}
}
```

Comment: Please post your code for BostadAdapter

Comment: I added it in the OP :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand properly, I think what you are doing is creating a new activity that looks identical to tab 2 but isn't the same object. So that activity you start in startActivity() is the only one that gets the data. What I would suggest is using a ViewPager with fragments and interfaces to pass/update data from the parent activity. That may be a bit too advanced yet and it's not something you can easily write out as an answer, however there are a lot of tutorials on the process. As you're just starting out you may want to explore faster options but it is what I'd do.

A quick fix might be to access the tab host and replace the existing tab 2 activity with the activity you just made that has the data.

Comment: Well no not really. What I actually want to do is update the listview that is in tab 2.

What I'm really do here is saving files and I want every single file that I save to be added to the listview in tab 2.

I'm passing an intent with the filename (streetname) and trying to add it to the listview.

Comment: Well the most common way to implement this type of structure these days is to create a single Activity that contains a ViewPager, some tab bar mechanism (your own or the ActionBar implementation) and fragments to be the pages in the ViewPager. In that model you can use listeners to notify the Activity that Tab1 did something and pass it data, then the Activity can notify Tab2 with the data and update the page showing the changes. If you want to use activities and pass data through an intent, you need to make sure that activity is replacing the old activity that doesn't have the data.

Comment: startActivity will start a new Activity, it won't update the old one. You could in theory, replace the activity in tab 2 with the new one you just created rather than calling startActivity but I wouldn't recommend that path.

Comment: This link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25096646/passing-edittext-value-from-an-activity-to-a-tab-in-android-tabhost

Comment: Hmm okey.
But my case, right now, is that I'm using tabHost. Is what I'm trying to achieve impossible without reworking the whole structure? It's based on TabHost and every tab is modified through an activity.

Comment: It should be possible, the link I posted showed a similar case and he solved it. It's just inefficient and lacking built in features like swiping right and left to change pages.

Comment: Alright I am going to check that out more. This seemed much easier in my mind.. :)

How do I even update my ListView though? Say I am in activity 2 and the onCreate is loaded. Is that syntax part correct? Feel like I'm just creating a new ArrayAdapter and everything once again.

Comment: Tried out his solution. As it probably does work I am getting a nullpointerexception since my app starts out in tab 1. I don't have a first activity like he does that he can pass an intent to.

So when the onCreate is called in my mainactivity, I will get an exception (which is what is happening).

Comment: I don't really get why it's so hard to update a listview in an existing tab? Am I using that such dumb methods to achieve it?

alternative solution: can I somehow list the name of all the saved files in the default directory?

Comment: Activities are meant to be their own self contained thing, if you want heavy interaction between two views you're going to be better off using an Activity that hosts two fragments, not two activities.

Comment: Alright thank you for the tips.
Been checking around a bit more and playing around. Seems that if I can manage to send the data back to the MainActivity (parent of the tabs) and then somehow send it to the tab I'll be fine.